# Nesting of several NavigationLink in a NavigationStack causes the loss of animation and breaks the backtracking

Tags: swift, swiftui

SwiftUI 4.0 introduces a new `NavigationStack` view.

Let's consider this simple structure.

```
struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
    static let sample = [Item(), Item(), Item()]
    let id = UUID()
}
```

When a `NavigationLink` is nested in another one, the navigation loses its animation and the backtracking takes directly to the root. Did I miss something, or is this a bug?

```
struct ItemDetailView: View {
    let item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.id.uuidString)
    }
}

struct ItemListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(Item.sample) { item in
            NavigationLink(item.id.uuidString, value: item)
        }
    }
}

struct ExploreView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                NavigationLink {
                    ItemListView()
                } label: {
                    Text("Items")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Explore")
        .navigationDestination(for: Item.self) { item in
            ItemDetailView(item: item)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ExploreView()
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mixed old (deprecated) and new variants of NavigationLink - that's bad thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to @Asperi's comment.

First, create a `Hashable` enum containing the destinations.

```
enum Destination: Hashable {
    case items
    
    var view: some View {
        switch self {
        case .items:
            return ItemListView()
        }
    }
    
    var title: LocalizedStringKey {
        switch self {
        case .items:
            return "Items"
        }
    }
}
```

Next, use the new `NavigationLink` initializer.

```
NavigationLink(Destination.items.title, value: Destination.items)
```

And finally, add a new `.navigationDestination` modifier to catch all `Destination` values.

```
.navigationDestination(for: Destination.self) { destination in
    destination.view
}
```